# Help identify MDF box with duct

Tags: hvac, insulation, ducts, mdf

Previous owners of my house left some sort of MDF box with a duct. There is insulation inside along with aluminum tape. There's some caulking around the duct and it looks like the box is broken up into 3 inner parts based on the screw pattern. There are no other openings beside the one with the duct.

I don't know what this is for but someone went through the effort of building it. Is it something common with a practical use that I should keep around or can this be thrown out?

Hoping someone can explain what this mysterious box is for.

[image: side view]
[image: front view]
[image: writing]

Comment: Is there another opening/duct on the box?  I would remove one side to see what is inside.

Comment: No extra openings.

Comment: including the bottom?

Comment: No, just some drawing on the back suggesting that a hole should be cut out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal HVAC boxes are not made of MDF.  This looks to be something made by the previous owners with some unknown plan.

It has no regular, common known use in a normal home. You may do with it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly good reuasble materials, at the least. Take it apart and store the parts, rather than throwing it out.

If it only has the one duct, and no other opening (you don't mention or show one) I have no idea. <s>If there's another opening it may be some kind of duct muffler or loud computer server enclosure.</s>

In any case, opening it up would provide more insight to what it might have been, and get you partway down the path to compact storage of reusable materials.

Comment: That was my initial though but it's all sealed up. I took out the screws from one side but couldn't get the board off. I think it's glued on. Added an extra photo that has a clue. Someone probably planned to cut out another hole. I want to make sure the box doesn't have a particular use as is before tearing it open.